# Firefly - getting rid of parts (dumping cargo)?

Tags: firefly

I just played Firefly the board game for the first time. I ended up with a ship modification that made spare parts invalid, but I had about 6 of them in my cargo hold. I was on a supply planet and wanted to buy fuel, but all of my cargo and stash spots were full. I looked for any thing in the rule book that talked about selling the spare parts (or dumping them)...couldn't find anything. What's protocol for getting rid of fuel or parts to make space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [official FAQ](http://www.fireflythegame.com/howtoplay/FAQ.aspx),

> Question: How do I get rid of stuff on my ship I don’t need or want anymore?
>
> Answer: On your turn, you may dump Fuel, Parts, Cargo or Contraband at any time. You may drop Fugitives and Passengers off in any sector with a Planet. You can’t toss them out the air-lock in deep space! This does not use an Action and can be done during another Action, on your turn.

You also have the option to trade with other players. From the rules,

> When two or more players’ ships are stopped in the same Sector, players may buy, sell and trade Crew, Fuel, Parts, Cargo, Contraband, Ship Upgrades and Gear to one another without restriction. Players are free to discuss and make these deals outside of the normal turn order and other players may take their normal turn while bargains are struck. Dealing with others players in this fashion does not require using an Action. The opportunity for Trading ends when one of the players leaves the sector.

There doesn't seem to be any option of selling back to the house, but we house-ruled they can be sold off at half-price at Suppliers. This has allowed people that would otherwise have been eliminated from the game to keep on playing.

Comment: Your house rule is of course fine, but if you felt it was necessary, did you by chance miss the "make work" rule that allows you to take $200 for a Work action on a planet?

Comment: @sitnaltax, No, I am aware of it.

Comment: Thanks. We used a house rule that it could be part of a buy phase, but will make it part of any action in the future. i also like the idea of the sell at 1/2 price when on a supply planet.

Answer (score 2):

You can space (dump out the airlock) anything, but you cannot dump passengers or fugitives unless there's a planet in the sector.  There is a crew member you can hire that allows you to sell parts to any solid contact, in addition to cargo and contraband.  You can also buy, sell, or trade any of these items (or fuel) with another firefly in the same sector.  These are the only ways to get rid of items in your cargo hold and stash.

Spacing things, selling to contacts, and trading with another firefly does not require an action, and can be done even if it's not your turn.